# WordPress - Woocommerce custom column on “Customer” sub-menu

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, customization

I am using Woocommerce to create one online shop and my requirement is to add a custom column in the customer sub-menu under the Woocommerce menu - highlighted in the following screenshot.

[image]

As this is not some custom post type table, I am unable to use `manage_edit-[posttype]_columns` cannot be used. I searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find any solution to that. Any help or hint to the answer is appreciated.

Thank you!